# Raspberry Pi GPIO error "valueerror the channel sent is invalid on a raspberry pi"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to check the GPIOs on a Modberry I have which also has an expansion board with theses GPIOS:
[image: GPIOS]

When running a simple python script to check the GPIO:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)    
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(38,GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(37,GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(505,GPIO.OUT)
```

And I got this error on the terminal:
[image: Terminal]

Do I have to configure the RPi.GPIO library to accepts these GPIO pins?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you're using a 3B or newer Raspberry Pi, it only has GPIO pin 40. So as the error message says, the "505" pin is invalid.

Comment: check this website for GPIO pins: https://pinout.xyz/

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got any errors for other pins, that means your GPIO library is configured properly.

While in line 10, you have put `GPIO.setup(505,GPIO.OUT)`. There is no pin 505 on rpi. Edit this as per your need. I assume it must be a typo.